# How do I remove hg-git entirely from Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: ubuntu, mbed, hg-git

When using mbed-cli to update an Mbed repo, I get the following error:

```
john@john-ThinkPad-Yoga-11e:~/Projects/myRepo$ mbed update
[mbed] Working path "/home/john/Projects/myRepo" (program)
[mbed] Updating program "myRepo" to latest revision in the current branch
[mbed] Updating library "mbed-os" to rev #c966348d3f9c (tag: mbed-os-5.11.1)
*** failed to import extension hggit from /path/to/hg-git: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/hg-git'
*** failed to import extension hggit from /path/to/hg-git: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/hg-git'
```

I do not want to use hg-git and have tried to remove it entirely. Mbed-cli uses Python so I tried various Python tools to remove hg-git but am still getting the error.  I am not even sure it is actually an error from mbed-cli as it appears after things that I know are part of mbed (ie, lines starting with "[mbed]"). I also tried to find the source of the error in a file (using 'grep -rnw . -e "hg-git"') but as a bit of a newb on Ubuntu I have not been able to do so.

Any ideas as to the source of the error message and/or how I might get rid of it and remove hg-git in its entirety?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `hggit` extension is still enabled in the Mercurial configuration.

You can show the file and line of where the configuration is set by running: `hg config extensions.hggit --template '{source}\n'`.

It may return something like `/home/user/.hgrc:12`. In this case, you have to remove or comment out line 12 in the file `/home/user/.hgrc` to disable the `hggit` extension.

Answer (score 0):

Use `apt` command to remove [hg-git](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/hg-git)

```
$ sudo apt remove hg-git
```

Comment: Thanks but I'd already done that.  I did so again to confirm with result: 'E: Unable to locate package hg-git'

Comment: You can use `sudo apt purge hg-git` to purge configuration files. Also, please try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133641

Comment: Same result with "purge" and nothing in the approved answer in the link seems applicable nor does it work:

./myRepo$ sudo apt purge hg-git
[sudo] password for john: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package hg-git
./myRepo$ python -c "import hggit"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named hggit
./myRepo$ head -n1 'which hg'
head: cannot open 'which hg' for reading: No such file or directory'

Comment: Use this: `sudo apt remove hg-git*` or `sudo apt remove hg-git --purge`

Comment: No luck, @Ho1, although a few new/different messages: ' ./myRepo$ sudo apt remove hg-git*
[sudo] password for john: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package hg-git*
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'hg-git*'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'hg-git*'
./myRepo$ sudo apt remove hg-git --purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package hg-git '